# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want show banner ad everything is working fine but when i install release apk to my phone there is grey screen. so when i debug again i got error:

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Positioned wants to apply ParentData of type StackParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type FlexParentData.

here is my code:

```
  Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Your elements here
            Positioned(child: Center(
              child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 320.0,
                  child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner)),
            ))
          ],
        ),
```

any solutions ?

I tried to removing positioned :

```
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Your elements here
             Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 320.0,
                  child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner)),
            
          ],
        ),
```

but no ads are shown

How to remove this error?

Comment: If removing the positioned didn't fix it then the problem is not in the top level widget it is in you adwidget. Update your answer to show adwidget code and I am sure someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your [**`Positioned`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) inside [**`Stack`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) Widget

```
 Stack(
       children: [
        Text('Your Widget'),
        Positioned( 
          child: Text(
            'Add Your Positioned widget inside Stack',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```